# How to launch the Marketplace in the Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to install app from Windows Phone Store to WP 8 emulator?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No you can't install apps from the store in the emulator, because you can't add a Microsoft account in the emulator which is required for installing apps from the store.

This is apparantly because the emulator is not seen as a trusted platform for Microsoft id. Here is an official answer from Microsoft to the same question:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/dfd9ba6f-1d18-486e-aa53-7d0a65d44f12

**Update for Windows Phone 8.1**

As Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen mentions in the comments, it is now possible to add a Microsoft account in the WP8.1 emulator, but still not possible to install apps (shows error message with code 80070002)

Comment: Thanks Johan.Sad but true.

Comment: Ye, I hope they add support for it later, would be nice now that they support launching other apps with URI's.

Comment: This is no longer correct. In the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator, you can add a Microsoft account just fine (however, it still won't go to the store).

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Thansk for the comment, but are you sure it is possible to download apps? I just tried in the WP8.1 emulator, while I can now log on to a Microsoft Account, I get an error "There is a problem completing yout request..." etc. with the error code "80070002". If it is possible I will of course update the answer! :)

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in the parantheses. I only said that a Microsoft account could be added, but the store issue remains.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Sorry, yes you did, I just read your comment to quickly to remember that part. :P

Comment: The emulator is x86, marketplace apps are ARM. Should be pretty obvious to everybody who it wouldn't work.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, only Windows based apps are ARM. Windows Phone should still be running X86-based CPUs in real life.

Answer (score 4):

Marketplace applications are run through the [native image generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx), so if they were not already compiled for ARM only, they will be once ngen have finished it's job.

And you obviously cannot install ARM applications on a x86 emulator.