# Deploying .xap file to Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, xap

I am trying to deploy some applications downloaded from marketplace to Windows Phone Emulator, but for every application it is showing error message ".xap file is invalid". What could be going wrong here? Any suggestions? I have tried to keep Emulator running as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't install apps from the store in the emulator, because you can't add a Microsoft account in the emulator which is required for installing apps from the store.

This is apparantly because the emulator is not seen as a trusted platform for Microsoft id. Here is an official answer from Microsoft to the same [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/dfd9ba6f-1d18-486e-aa53-7d0a65d44f12):

Source: [How to launch the Marketplace in the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914208/how-to-launch-the-marketplace-in-the-windows-phone-8-emulator)

Comment: Jibran, Thanks for the help. What I am trying to do is downloading an app from marketplace(for manual installation) and then deploying it to an emulator by using XapDeploy utility. Is that possible? XapDeploy list Windows Phone Emulator as a valid device.

Comment: Still its not possible to acheive this because the emulator does'nt have a valid id to be registered against the application in the store.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't install a downloaded .XAP file from the windows store in the emulator, due to emulator is not a trusted platform for the Microsoft Live ID.

Answer (score 1):

Ya exactly correct.To deploy any .xap file you must need to registered your device with Microsoft Live ID. Emulator will never accepted it,because emulator is not a trusted platform for the Microsoft Live ID. So it is not possible for installing downloaded .XAP file from the windows store in the emulator.