# Error 80070002 when installing apps from Store on Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, hyper-v

This happens when trying to install any application from the Store on Windows Phone 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB Emulator. It first asks to login with Microsoft account, create a backup and such. Then after pressing the install button for some app an error dialog appears.

Complete message from error dialog:

> There is a problem completing your request. Try again later.
>
> Inquiring minds may find this error code helpful: 80070002
>
> [Close]

I tried following solutions from [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ba179a4-6b40-45fd-b921-39cfb5ed189d/windows-phone-81-cortana-error-code-80070002?forum=winphoneosissues), which is enabling Administrator account, logging in (so that C:\Users\Administrator folder appears) and restarting Emulator. Unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: It means "file not found".  Pretty doubtful anybody here can find that file for you.  Use the emulator only to debug your app, not to run arbitrary Store apps.

Comment: There should at least be a way to debug this and figure out which file is missing. I used to have multiple Store apps installed on a WP8 emulator running on another machine back in the days. This one looks like some accounts/Hyper-V/permissions issue.

Comment: I have this same issue. I need the 3rd party app to debug my website.

Comment: so I have the same issue using Windows Phone emulator and trying to install Microsoft Health app from Windows App store. Any solution to this you found already? I am sure my account works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch the Marketplace in the Windows Phone 8 Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914208/how-to-launch-the-marketplace-in-the-windows-phone-8-emulator)

Comment: Don't quite agree since this question tackles the error itself. Also, answer to the other question is not satisfying to someone wanting to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 5):

Check the date; time and region settings in your emulator. They need to be correct.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, I played around with these settings, nothing helped so far.

Comment: FYI, this is also true of a real Win 8.1 Phone. It seems to NOT update it's time over WiFi, so you have to manually set the time. The store error should really be more clear about this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the phone does not get the connection to your Microsoft account. Hence do the following steps:

1. log into your Microsoft account and see that all is ok (address and payment option) - if it is messed up you will have to chat to support "account and billing"
2. log in on windowsphone.com: make sure that you see your phone there if you are not sure whether it is your phone, click "find, lock, erase my phone" and it will bring you to the Microsoft account website where it will show you the IMEI number - check on your phone that it is the same
3. On your phone go to settings ==> backup: click "back up now" for apps and settings
4. on your phone go to settings "email + accounts" click on Microsoft account and hold until "sync" comes and then sync

If the problem still not solved:

1. log in on a PC on www.windowsphone.com
2. in the store buy the app you want to buy
3. now you should see the app in "purchase history" on the windows phone website
4. beside the app on the history click on "reinstall" - it will change and say "contacting your phone"
5. on your phone you should see the app downloading and installing
6. once the app is downloaded, go to the store on your phone and chose "my apps" (from the ...) - now you should see all your apps and no error anymore

Comment: The app is free and can't be bought and is not available for Windows. It is Microsoft Health and when I try to install it in Emulator I get the same error as Jaccus. Your solution didn't help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think its about architecture mismatch. Also check if the app is already installed on emulator or not.

Comment: or maybe IMEI of emulator is blocked with the Store... just a guess.