# Install a Windows Phone App Store app in an enumlator

Tags: windows-phone

I've been asked to look at an application that's available on the Windows Phone App Store, however I don't have access to a physical Windows Phone.

Is it possible to use an emulator to install and run such an app?

Comment: I wasn't able to using the Windows Phone 8 emulator.  Here's another question very similar to yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914208/how-to-launch-the-marketplace-in-the-windows-phone-8-emulator

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use emulator. 
- install visual studio 2013 update 2 or vs 2015.
- install windows phone emulators (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719).

Comment: Does running such an emulator allow you to install apps from the Windows App Store?

Comment: yes.i f, once in the emulator, you enter the store, you sign up with an email and you can download and use applications. Regards !!

Comment: Have you actually tried this yourself? Can you share a screenshot, showing it working? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914774/24874) suggests it's not possible to do what you're saying.

Comment: I was able to get this far too, however attempting to install an app failed. Do you have a screenshot showing successful installation?